# BiqQuery Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [3:7]- fixed, but don't know why the fix worked

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, integer, concatenation, syntax-error

My original syntax:

```sql
SELECT
users
CONCAT(start_station_name, "to", end_station_name) AS route
COUNT (*) as num_trips,
ROUND (AVG(cast(tripduration/int60),2) AS duration)
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips'
GROUP BY start_station, end_station, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The one that I changed to after reading about solutions:

```sql
SELECT usertype, 
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route, 
  COUNT (*) as num_trips,
  ROUND (AVG(tripduration/60), 2) AS duration
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY 
  usertype, start_station_name, end_station_name 
ORDER BY 
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Why did the second one work when the first one wouldn't? I know it has to do with the `(AVG(cast(tripduration/int60),2) AS duration)` part, because the schema already put the trip duration in integers, but why was the error on the `CONCAT(start_station_name, "to", end_station_name)` line?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: because you're missing `comma`